# How to use Derby.js model arrays?

Tags: arrays, model, push, derbyjs

I keep getting `Fatal error: [object Object] is not an Array` and then a server crash, whenever I try to use Derby.js/Racer's model array methods, (`push`, `insert`) for example.

```
app.ready (model)->
   model.set 'list', []
   model.push 'list', 'test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/codeparty/racer/issues/71

The root model has to an object. So the below would work.

```
app.ready (model)->
    model.set 'list.list', []
    model.push 'list.list', 'test'
```